# Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'external/jansson' in import path

Tags: cocos2d-x

i'm developing a Game with Cocos2d-x 3.3, using Google Play Games (gpg-cpp-sdk for android) and Soomla Store/Core.

When execute ./build_native under proj.android i get this error:

```
$ ./build_native.py
The Selected NDK toolchain version was 4.8 !
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-19 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 10 in ./AndroidManifest.xml
Android NDK: /Applications/Cocos/frameworks/cocos2d-x/extensions/soomla-cocos2dx-core/Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'external/jansson' in import path
Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ?
Android NDK: The following directories were searched:
Android NDK:
make: Entering directory `/Users/Jesus/<project_name>/proj.android'
/Applications/Cocos/frameworks/cocos2d-x/extensions/soomla-cocos2dx-core/Android.mk:33: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
make: Leaving directory `/Users/Jesus/<project_name>/proj.android'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./build_native.py", line 160, in <module>
    build(opts.ndk_build_param,opts.android_platform,opts.build_mode)
  File "./build_native.py", line 147, in build
    do_build(cocos_root, ndk_root, app_android_root,ndk_build_param,sdk_root,android_platform,build_mode)
  File "./build_native.py", line 83, in do_build
    raise Exception("Build dynamic library for project [ " + app_android_root + " ] fails!")
Exception: Build dynamic library for project [ /Users/Jesus/<project_name>/proj.android ] fails!
```

My Android.mk in /Applications/Cocos/frameworks/cocos2d-x/extensions/soomla-cocos2dx-core/Android.mk is:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# cocos2dx-soomla-common
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := cocos2dx_soomla_common_static
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libcocos2dxsoomlacommon

CORE_SRC_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/Soomla/*.cpp)
CORE_SRC_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/Soomla/domain/*.cpp)
CORE_SRC_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/Soomla/data/*.cpp)
CORE_SRC_LIST += $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/Soomla/rewards/*.cpp)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(CORE_SRC_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/Soomla
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/Soomla/data
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/Soomla/domain
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/Soomla/rewards

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocos2dx_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += jansson_static
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cocostudio_static


LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/Soomla
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/Soomla/data
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/Soomla/domain
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/Soomla/rewards

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,external/jansson)
```

Anyone can you help me?

Comment: Try posting the question on the Soomla forum: http://answers.soom.la/

Answer (score 1):

in build_native.py, find ndk_module_path in function

`def do_build(cocos_root, ndk_root, app_android_root, ndk_build_param,sdk_root,build_mode):`

when command $(call import-module,external/jansson) runs , "external/jasson" is the relative path from ndk_module_path, check whether android.mk exists there

Answer (score 1):

```
Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ?
```

set the NDK_MODULE_PATH in eclipse,add cocos engine and external in properties->c/c++ build->Environment

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. need set the variable NDK_MODULE_PATH to my path of ndk, no? Need to add "cocos engine and external" to path?